# iText 7 how to set font for the entire documents in

Tags: java, spring, itext

I am using iText 7 to create a PDF in a java Spring project. I know how to set a font for an element like a paragraph or cell in a table, as shown in the snippet below.  How can I set a font and size for the entire document?

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream()));

    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("Paragraph 1").setFont(font);

    ...
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set font to `Document` like this:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc).setFont(font).setFontSize(10);
```

Comment: `Document` class **does not** have `setFont` method.

Comment: @MHSFisher, Which version of Itext did you imported? Read the last version [document](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/Document.html), `Methods inherited from class com.itextpdf.layout.ElementPropertyContainer`